# double drawer from the same side ? android drawerlayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, drawerlayout

in my app i need to display two drawers from the right sides, menu + notifications.

so here is my xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainContent">


    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/notification_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#111"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_drawer_notifications" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_drawer_menu" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This snipped of code was working, and  menu drawer + notification drawer was displayed from the right side. but now i don't know what's happened, i just come back to my old code and it doesn't work. the app crashes and it shows this error:

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Child drawer has absolute gravity RIGHT but this DrawerLayout already has a drawer view along that edge
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure_Original(DrawerLayout.java:1089)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
```

Comment: I really don't see how this ever worked. How is the `DrawerLayout` to know which drawer to open upon dragging? A preferable solution would probably be to make the drawer `View` an empty container `ViewGroup` that you can transact your `Fragment`s into as needed.

Comment: How is the user supposed to open one drawer or another? DrawerLayout wont let you do this, you should change the drawer content instead.

Comment: @MikeM. i hvae disabled dragging. i swear it was working

Comment: @Nanoc using openDrawer(View drawerView) i can decide which drawer to open

Comment: Well, then I would say it was a fluke. You won't need/want to have them both open simultaneously anyway, so dynamically transacting the `Fragment`s as necessary is going to be a more solid solution.

Comment: That has sense only if you open it with buttons, go with Mike solution and change drawer content instead of having two drawers.

Comment: Thank you all, i will do what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've set both fragments gravity end, check this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    />
```

now there is some methods and classes used at the main activity

```
assert drawer != null;
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

### toggle.syncState();

```
        assert drawer != null;
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `DrawerLayout` doesn't support double drawer at the same side, you can extend `DrawerLayout` and change some method to support it.

see this [file](https://gist.github.com/AssIstne/1835aecddba676843adc1070537d40b8)

It was commented by Chinese. However, the class did two things

1. handles the exception thrown by `DrawerLayout#onMeasure`, and measures the second drawer itself.
2. handles the `ACTION_UP` touch event when clicking in the shadow to close the first drawer.

NOTE: the class is from a demo, so you should not copy to use it directly. Try to understand it and modify it to feed your need. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same feature these days. Wrap a DrawerLayout inside the outer DrawerLayout can meet the request. The layout xml looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:overScrollMode="never"
app:layout_anchorGravity="right"
tools:openDrawer="end"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- main content -->
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_filters"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- right drawer content -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- inner right drawer content -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/app_green_normal"
        android:id="@+id/lv_filter_options"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

One things need to notice is, the inner drawer cannot be drag out. You need to call openDrawer and closeDrawer when you want to open and close.